# how to run python project after remove .py file?

Tags: python, copy-protection

i want to remove my source code .py files to avoid rivals to see my code.

so i use

```
python -c "import compileall; compileall.compile_dir('D:/acc')"
```

to compile all py files to pyc,next step is to remove py files,and run the project only use pyc, how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One convenient approach is to rename the main module pyc file to `__main__.pyc` and put all pyc files in a zip file. Python 2.6 and above are then able to run the zip:

```
python myapplication.zip
```

Be aware that pyc files are not compatible between different Python versions.

Comment: can you tell it in details? i renamed my entry pyc file to __main__.pyc as you said and package the whole package to a zip file.but when i run the zip file python told me can't find __main__ module

Comment: What you did sounds right. One possible cause to that error message is trying to use a different Python version to run. Python will look for the corresponding .py file if the .pyc file is not compatible, and complain.

Answer (score 6):

you can use shutils, which is in the standard lib but please consider that removing *.py files is not a very string protection as it is very easy to rebuild the *.py file from a *.pyc.

Using py2exe with a drm packer would be much more secure.

Comment: i know but first, the project will be running on linux,windows only for a test,second pyc is enough for my case